# Angular2 - Component is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, semantic-ui

I have this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tOlObEQTAPH6jdjRC1Ub?p=preview), with a small angular2 example, If you open the Chrome console, you will see my error.

```
Error: ArticleComponent is not defined(…)Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243
```

What happens with my code?

**Somthing more, Why my style is not resolved?**

Can somebody help to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: `import {RedditApp} from './intermediates/component1'`, your class is named ArticleComponent not RedditApp, and you need to add `export` to it as well.

Comment: Thanks, that was my error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know absolutely any Angular 2 (other than a couple tutorials made for fun), but if you `export class ArticleComponent` in line 43 of `component1.ts` (instead of just defining the class) it seems to work :-)